# In PlayN, how do you exclude a directory from being compiled by Maven?

Tags: maven, playn

I want to build the html version of my game from the command line using maven. However, when I run the `package` command for the `core` folder:

```
mvn clean package -pl core,html
```

I get the following errors because of some unit tests in my source path:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/klenwell/projects/mygame/playn/mygame/core/src/main/java/mygame/playn/tests/unit/UserDataTest.java:[3,23] package org.junit does not exist

[ERROR] /home/klenwell/projects/mygame/playn/mygame/core/src/main/java/mygame/playn/tests/unit/UserDataTest.java:[7,16] package org.junit does not exist

...
```

How can I exclude the directory with these test files from being included in the compilation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following block to the `plugins` section of my core `pom.xml` file excluded tests from compilation and allowed the build to succeed:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*Test*.java</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not a good idea to mix `source` and `test` classes.  As per maven convention, you should move the tests from `src/main/java` to `src/test/java`.

You should add the dependency for `junit` so that the tests can be compiled.

You can choose to skip the tests (if they are broken) by using the `-DskipTests` or similar while running maven.

Comment: Thanks. Still getting acquainted with Maven and Java conventions.