# How do I add support of custom JavaScript event triggers in PlayN?

Tags: javascript, html, playn

I am trying to make a PlayN game that will need to take controls from some non-standard javascript triggers (hardware buttons on the device) in the HTML5 version. The Android, iOS versions will all be pretty standard.

Where do I look to wire this up?

Also, (probably a dumb one) what is the best way to export the built HTML5 for release on the web server?

Thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 0):

Each project comes with specific sub projects for each of the platforms, that where you would put your html 5 specific code.

[Build your HTML project from the command line.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892062/in-playn-how-can-i-build-the-html-version-of-my-project-from-the-command-line/10899856#10899856)